# Why is deserializeUser not being called? Angular and Express

Tags: angular, typescript, express, passport.js

I've already read all the questions related to mine on stack overflow and everywhere else where I could find...

I can not solve my problem...

I am using Angular and Express...

I use withCredentials

this is my **app.ts** file / app.js once compiled

```
import express = require('express');
import dotenv = require('dotenv');
import router from './routes';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import session = require('express-session');
import passport from 'passport';

dotenv.config();

const secret_key: string = (process.env.SECRET_KEY as string);

const app: express.Application = express();


// Add headers
const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
    allowedHeaders: [
        'Origin',
        'X-Requested-With',
        'Content-Type',
        'Accept',
        'X-Access-Token',
    ],
    credentials: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    preflightContinue: false,
};
app.use(cors(options));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.options('*', cors(options));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'test-secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000/* 2 hours */, secure: false }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(passport.initialize(), router);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Hello world app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`));
```

passport.js file where serialise an deserialise are.

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { knex } from './knex/knex';

export default () => {
    passport.serializeUser((user: any, done: any) => {
        console.log('inside ser');
        done(null, user.userId);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((userId: any, done: any) => {
        console.log('inside des');
        knex('accounts').where({userId: userId}).first()
        .then((user) => { done(null, user); console.log(user)})
        .catch((err) => { done(err, null); console.log(`deserialoize Error ${err}`) });
    });
}
```

local.js init is for serialise and deserialise

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';

import init = require('../passport');
import { knex } from '../knex/knex';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const options = {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
};

init.default();

export default passport.use(new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) => {
    knex('accounts').where({userEmail: username}).first()
    .then((user) => {
        if (!user) return done(null, false)
        if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.userPassword)) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        else {
            return done(null, user);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => { return done(err); });
}));
```

this is my user controller

```
export const userLogIn = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    
    passport.default.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) { res.status(500).send('error'); console.log(err)}
        if (!user) { res.status(404).send('User not found!'); }
        if (user)
        {
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) { res.status(500).send('error'); console.log(err)}
                res.status(200);
            });
        }
    })(req, res);
}
```

this is how I do the request from angular

```
logInUser(value: any): void{
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/login', value, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(data => {
      //let user: User = data;
      //console.warn(data);
    });
  }
```

I've been struggling almost 2 days...

I know it is not the best typescript code, I keep improving it as I learn, but right now I want to solve this issue and I don't think it is related to typescript.

If it helps, I checked the sessionID and it is the same, also the session is stored in request with the maxAge that I've set etc

but there is no request.user on requests that come from angular

and **serializeUser** is being called but **deserializeUser** not

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo in your method. Please note that passport adds the `req.login` method *not* `req.logIn`.

Comment: Hello @jasonandmonte look at this image https://ibb.co/g7JpH9D I have both options, logIn and login, logOut and logout